# ROBLOX: Message not popping in output after health is 0

Tags: lua, roblox

I am trying to create some sort of point system in Roblox. I would like it to add 150 points to my score after I kill the Humanoid, but my script isn't doing anything. Any pointers? I am new to this.

Check my code [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HgcMR.png) or just read it below:

```lua
local function score(points)
    score = 0
    local points = score + 150
    if game.Workspace.Dummy.Humanoid.Health == 0 then
        print("good")
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Signal Died ()`:
http://wiki.roblox.com/index.php?title=API:Class/Humanoid/Died

> Description: Fired after a character's health reaches 0. Which could be caused either by disconnecting their head from their torso, or directly setting the health property.

This should provide you an event for when your Humanoid dies.

Something like this:

```
game.Workspace.Dummy.Humanoid.Died:connect(function()
    print("good")
end)
```

Comment: I've been trying to understand whats posted in that link. Not really understanding much. How would I implement that in my code?

Comment: Edited with a possible example. You may need to look into events further to use them with your scoring system as it seems like you want the score to be unique for each player.

Comment: Yeah i'll look into it more. Thank you!